# Bootstrap 3 Popover on click AND hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using jquery javascript and css to make a popover working as a link trigger that shows the popover from a div BUT what I really need is that it shows on HOVER and also on click.

The current code I have is working if I click the link BUT I require it so that its on hover.

THE JS:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({});
$('[data-toggle="click"]').popover();$(function(){ $('[rel=popover]').popover({ html : true, content: function() { return $('.popover_content_wrapper').html(); } }); });
```

AND THE HTML:

```
<li class="menu-call"><a href="#" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="Call Sales"><i class="icon-phone"></i><b>Call Sales</b></a>
```

Its working great if i click the link but its not ideal and I want it to do these things:

1. Pop up on hover (as I intend using it as a kind of tooltip) but also for click (to please the mobile users)
2. call the content from an INTERNAL URL so to not pollute the html code. My footer where the current div wrapper:popover_content_wrapper resides would be extremely large if i added everything in there. So calling an internal file to display the contents is a must.
3. remove the # from the URL (that gets added IF i use the click method)

Comment: Please select the below answer as the final answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually include this in the element: `data-trigger="hover click"`

So in your example:

```
<a href="#" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover click" data-placement="bottom" title="Call Sales"><i class="icon-phone"></i><b>Call Sales</b></a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Great SIMPLE answer. Works like a charm :) Do you by any chance have answers for the other questions i posed? to call the popover from an internal URL? guessing there is a simple answer for this too which I am missing somewhere.. thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi jona, great resource, thanks. Any ideas on how to get the tooltip to hide on click at any other place of the app different from the icon? Here's a question I just posted about that in case you have an input: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75539009/12372421.